# PHP/MYSQL Multiply each column of every row by chosen value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a multiplying system to give consumers results on the product that I think they would like. I am pretty new at PHP and MYSQL so if you can add little explanations that would be great! If not then I will figure it out!

So each product gets a rating from 1-3. 
___________________________________________
Name    |    Softness    |    Warmth
Item 1  |        2       |         1
Item 2  |        3       |         3
Item 3  |       ...      |        ...
...     |       ...      |        ...

On the product page it asks the consumer what they are looking for.

Softness [menu 1-3]
Warmth [menu 1-3]

I want the dropdown menu value to multiply with the column values in the mysql database.

Customer chooses softness: 1 and warmth: 2
Item 1 : 2, 2
Item 2: 3, 6
Item 3: etc
Continues with all products

Then it would display the top 3 items with the highest values.

Question Page:

```
How important is softness in your product?
<input id="1" type="radio" name="softness" value="-1.0">
<label for="1">Not very important</label>
<input id="2" type="radio" name="softness" value="0" checked>
<label for="2">Neutral</label>
<input id="3" type="radio" name="soft" value="1.0">
<label for="3">Very important</label>

How important is warmth in your product?
<input id="1" type="radio" name="warmth " value="-1.0">
<label for="1">Not very important</label>
<input id="2" type="radio" name="warmth " value="0" checked>
<label for="2">Neutral</label>
<input id="3" type="radio" name="warmth " value="1.0">
<label for="3">Very important</label>

This is all I got so far...

    <?php

    // Connect SQL 
    include"database/sqlcon.php";

    // Select Database
    $query = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM product LIMIT 3"
    );

    if(!$query) {
    die(mysql_error());
    }

    // Get Form Values
    $softness= $_POST['softness'];
    $warmth= $_POST['warmth'];

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $productname = $row['product'];
    $productsoft= $row['soft'];
    $productwarm = $row['warm'];

    }

    $totalsoft = $productsoft * $softness; 
     $totalwarm = $productwarm * $warmth;

    mysql_close();

    ?>
```

Comment: Please do add your code.

Comment: Added it! I wasn't sure if it was of any help

Comment: _"Then it would display the top 3 items with the highest values."_ What do you mean by that? how is the highest value calculated? Is it the sum of relative softness and hardness both, Or do sort the result by columns of different priority.

Comment: It would be the totalsoftness + totalswarmth.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a post, and you are using mysql [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
   $items = $db->query("select * from items");
   $row_items = $items->fetch();
   $weight_values = array();
   $x= 0;

   do{
      $weight_values[$x]['1'] = $_POST['Softness']*$row_items['softness'];
      $weight_values[$x]['2'] = $_POST['Warmth']*$row_items['warmth'];
      $x++;
   }while($row_items = $items->fetch());

}
```

Then you can just echo out the values from the array.
Basically you are accessing all the information from your items table, then you are going to go through it 1 by 1 in the while loop. For each row you are going to multiply the value in the database by the posted value, you are then going to put that value into an array.

You can then access that array by using

```
echo $weight_values[0][1]; //for item with id 1 softness value
echo $weight_values[0][2]; //for item with id 1 warmth value
```

If you are using [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) which you shouldn't as given by the reason in the link

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
   $query_items("select * from items");
   $items = mysql_query($query_items,$items_db) or die(mysql_error());
   $row_items = mysql_fetch_assoc($items);
   $weight_values = array();
   $x= 0;

   do{
      $weight_values[$x]['1'] = $_POST['Softness']*$row_items['softness'];
      $weight_values[$x]['2'] = $_POST['Warmth']*$row_items['warmth'];
      $x++;
   }while($row_items = mysql_fetch_assoc($items));

}
```

Comment: Hi there, I am pretty new at all this. Could you possibly give me a  little explanation on what everything does?

Comment: `$x` shouldn't be in quotes.

Comment: cool thanks Barmar, was editing and changed your edits feel free to change it again, much appreciated

Comment: Hi I was trying out the code and I got Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line $row_items = $items->fetch();

Answer (score 0):

A pure Mysql Implementation considering that,

1. All the inputs are sanitized & escaped.
2. All other programing principles / factors / Good Practices are taken care of.

IMHO is as follows,

```
select
  *,
  softness * '. $softness .' + warmth * '. $warmth .' as totalindexy
from items2
order by totalindexy DESC
LIMIT 3 -- Then it would display the top 3 items with the highest values
```

and this method has a few benefits,

1. Less data travels between `MySQL` and `php`
2. You don't need to post-process it afterwards in php, since it already gives you the best three options.
3. If the table is huge as in no of rows, then this solution is better, as importing the whole table to `php` and sorting/filtering the top three **may** produce memory limit errors.

**Update 1 :-** *Regarding the Syntax Error.*

Here is a [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d43f3/1/0) to prove/explain the working of my solution.

**The customary warning :-**

Please start using **MySQLi** instead of **MySQL** A.S.A.P. since not doing so shall put the security of your application at huge risk.

Comment: Hi there, is "items2" supposed the table name in the database?

Comment: Yeah, that would be your table name.

Comment: I have to agree if you are only wanting the top 3 and are going to do nothing more with the values, this is a nice solution

Comment: I get this issue here trying to use your code. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM products; LIMIT 3' at line 5

Comment: @user2515606 Did you try removing the comment in the last line in SQL?

Comment: I got a new error after remove a comma. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(softness * -1) + (warmth * 1)' at line 2. -1 is from the "Not important" and Warmth as "IMportant"

Comment: I've updated my answer, also Remember you can always try to fiddle with the apostrophes / concatenation / variable replacement in the `php` code, since sometimes php tends to be a bit fuzzy ;)

Comment: @user2515606 did you check out the fiddle link that I gave, did it run flawlessly? If it did, then there's gotta be a problem in your `php` code, right? Now I can help you only this far, since I *don't know* your development/production *environment*, actual full code access or *your level of expertise* , so all I can recommend you is keep trying in the php code, and if all else fails you can always *just ask a new question* regarding this new problem, that you encounter. Happy coding!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85052/discussion-between-user2515606-and-mohd-abdul-mujib).

Comment: How do I make it so it displays the top 3 ?

Comment: @user2515606 It already is displaying the top 3, `order by totalindexy DESC` & `LIMIT 3` are the lines doing the trick.